# antd table onChange sorter not getting "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, antd

I have created a antd table in react with all the data. I needed to implement a sort function for two of the column `Name` and `Last Updated At`. For that I used the `onChange={(val:any, filter:any, sorter:any})` function of the antd table and get the `sorter` value from it and passing it a function called `handleChange(val, sorter)` like this.

```
const handleChange = (val: any, sorter: any) => {
    console.log(val, sorter);
    if (sorter.order === "ascend") {
      setSortOrderRaw("asc");
    } else if (sorter.order === "descend") {
      setSortOrderRaw("desc");
    } else if (sorter.order === undefined) {
      setSortOrderRaw("");
    }

    if (sorter.columnKey !== undefined) {
      setSortFieldRaw(sorter.columnKey);
    } else {
      setSortFieldRaw("");
    }

    setPageSizeOther(val?.pageSize);
    setCurrentPageOther(val?.current);
};
```

and added `sortOrderRaw` and `sortFieldRaw` as the dependencies of the `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(() => {
      getData();
  }, [
    pageSizeOther,
    currentPageOther,
    sortOrderRaw,
    sortFieldRaw,
  ]);
```

So `getData()` function should trigger every time `sortOrderRaw` changes.

Issue is when I click the column header to sort, its order of sorting should be `ascend`, `descend` and then order should become `undefined` but here its following order `descend`, `ascend`, ***`ascend`***, `descend`, `ascend`, ***`ascend`***. Bold and Italic `ascend` should become `undefined` then only `getData()` function will trigger and populate the table without any sorting. but here as its getting `ascend` in successive clicks `getData()` function not triggering as the state is not changing.

Note: Even the tool tip also not showing `click to cancel sorting` instead it showing `click to sort ascending` for the successive clicks.

```
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
      loading={loading}
      pagination={{
        current: currentPage,
        pageSize,
        total,
        showQuickJumper: true,
        showSizeChanger: true,
      }}
      sortDirections={["ascend", "descend"]}
      onChange={(val: any, filter: any, sorter: any, extra: any) => {
        handleChange(val, sorter);
      }}
    />
```

respective Columns

```
  const columns: any[] = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      width: "20%",
      sorter: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Last Updated On",
      key: "CreatedAt",
      sorter: true,
      render: (_: any, record: any) => {
        return DateTime.fromMillis(record.CreatedAt).toFormat(
          "dd:MM:yyyy,  hh:mm:ss a",
        );
      },
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `sortDirections={["ascend", "descend"]}` from your Table configuration. Your configuration is telling Table to use only 2 options, not 3 which you want.

With your code created Sample https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-butterfly-85ot6v

Comment: I tried removing it as well but it not working.

Comment: From your example created a sample. Please check and check out the console. It prints asc,desc, "" as you set in `sortOrderRaw`